# USB Drive not being recognized

Tags: usb-drive

I have a Kingston DataTraveler 100 G3 (64GB) and it is not being recognized by ubuntu. I tested in 3 different machines. It is not even being listed with lsusb (lsusb will give the same output with or without the drive plugged in).

The same drive works fine on Windows and OSX.

```
~ ⤙ uname -r
3.19.0-32-generic
```

Using dmesg, when connected the drive

```
[ 9014.917718] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
[ 9014.958752] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666
[ 9014.958757] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 9014.958760] usb 2-1: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[ 9014.958763] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 9014.958765] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 60A44C413841FE604992008C
```

and a while after connected

```
[ 9064.754262] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 9064.757892] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 9064.761382] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 9064.761391] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9064.761580] scsi host182: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[ 9064.765126] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 9064.768625] usb 2-1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 9064.768767] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 53
```

**More information**

**What format is the drive in? What filesystem?** 
I've tried with NTFS and EXFAT

**Any files on it?** 
Nope

**What have you tried to fix it?**
I tried to use Disks utility but the drive is not listed. Tried lsusb and it is not listed as well.

Comment: Is the drive by any chance NFTS or EXFAT ? Do you have the drivers for those  disk formats installed?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/759520/edit) your question with answers (if you have them) to the following questions: What format is the drive in? What filesystem? Any files on it? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Answered. Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoAcras Thank you so much **;)** I'll get back to you when I find out how you could re-format, considering you don't have files, you have no reason not to.

Comment: @Videonauth This is not filesystem-related at all. If it is not even listed by lsblk, it's not detected by the kernel.